# Зачем нужны Lock в asyncio

Tags: python, asyncio

Не понял для себя следующий момент в python asyncio.

> ```
> class asyncio.Lock(*, loop=None)
> ```
>
> Implements a mutex lock for asyncio tasks. Not thread-safe. An asyncio
> lock can be used to guarantee exclusive access to a shared resource.

Имеем, что это блокировка нужна внутри одного потока, когда разные короутины могут получить доступ к одному объекту одновременно. В этой статье https://python-gino.org/docs/en/1.0/explanation/async.html в том числе описывается, что так как мы работаем в одном потоке, то одновременно код из разных короутин не может изменять состояние какой либо переменной в одном потоке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным помечено выполнение кода, зеленым ожидание ввода вывода.

Так в чем я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Если корутина между несколькими изменениями переменной сделает await, то управление может получить другая корутина и попытаться изменить ту же переменную — возможно, для таких случаев Lock и нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй случай. Задача нужно принять данные из нескольких источников, сгруппировать  и отправить дальше.

Запускаем таск отправки

```
async def sender(lock1, lock2):
    while True:
        async with lock1, lock2:
            await send(data)
```

А в приемниках используем lock1 и lock2. Тогда отправка исполнится, когда будут готовы обе компоненты. И при этом data будет прикрыта от изменений на время отправки

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, например, короутниа1 делает запрос на изменение ключа в редис, после этого происходит переключение в короутина2.
Короутина2 тоже изменяет тот же ключ в редисе.
Далее выполнение опять переключается на первую короутину в которую приходит ответ о том, что ключ сохранен.

А на самом деле значение ключа было переписано во второй короутине.
Может это ответ на мой вопрос ?